# Multiple participant types in a business network

Tags: hyperledger-composer

How do you handle multiple participant types in the network? If I model an auctioneer, I may want that to be an extension of a user.

Answer (score 1):

The following example outlines what your looking for

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/carauction-network/models/auction.cto

```
abstract participant User identified by email {
  o String email
  o String firstName
  o String lastName
}

participant Member extends User {
 o Double balance
}

participant Auctioneer extends User {
}
```